# office 365 rest api's for querying office 365 domain users

Tags: active-directory, office365, azure-active-directory, office365-apps

Can you please provide me the API names using which I can create,delete,update,search for users in office 365 without azure AD.

Answer (score 4):

All Office365 subscriptions are backed by Azure AD directories. All Office365 users (pure cloud ones, as well as ones connected to on-premises AD) are Azure AD identities.

You should use the Azure AD Graph API read/write Office365 users (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974478.aspx).

Use the Office365 REST APIs to read/write entities specific to O365 services (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974478.aspx).

Comment: Both of those links are dead now. Google Microsoft Graph instead.